# installing yeoman-generator and then not find it

Tags: angularjs, npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I keep install yo generator like  angular, angular-fullstack, cg-angular using those commands:

```
npm install -g generator-angular
npm install -g generator-angular-fullstack
npm install -g generator-cg-angular
```

But when I try to use them with yo command I don't find them

```
You don't seem to have a generator with the name angular:controller installed.
You can see available generators with npm search yeoman-generator and then install them with npm install [name].
To see the 1 registered generators run yo with the `--help` option.


? 'Allo Noor! What would you like to do? 
  Run a generator
  Webapp 
  ──────────────
  Update your generators 
  Install a generator 
  Find some help 
❯ Get me out of here! 
  ──────────────
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you use "npm clean cache" and try to use the same commands can solve.